# What's the difference between /etc/hosts and /system/etc/hosts in Android?

Tags: android, config, symlink, hosts

I was navigating the "/" directories on my android and came across two "hosts" files, one in `/etc` and the other in `/system/etc` which had the same contents. Are there any differences between these two files or are they same? I also noticed that they had the same contents in them saying `127.0.0.1 localhost`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they are both the same file. One is a symbolic link to the other.

Further reading:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)